# Question about translation

Tags: phrases, verbs

Is it grammatically correct to say: "Hello, I also have a question, Is the movie translated in spanish or it just include subtitles?"

Comment: Are you asking about the grammaticality of the question?

Comment: @Havok, did one of these answers below answer your question? If so, please accept the answer that worked for you. If not, let us know so that we can help.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it grammatically correct to say: "Hello, I also have a question, Is the movie translated in spanish or it just include subtitles?"

This should be listed as two separate sentences; alternatively, you could connect them with a semicolon (as I have done in this sentence).

The other significant grammatical error is "...or it just include subtitles?" That would be better phrased as: "...or does it just include subtitles?"

The comma before "or" is appropriate because you are joining two independent clauses with a coordinating conjunction.

Don't forget to capitalize "Spanish" (it's a proper noun). And I find that "translated into" is more common than "translated in" for this type of usage.

Altogether, I would write it as:

> "Hello, I also have a question. Is the movie translated into Spanish, or does it just include subtitles?"

Answer (score 0):

From a gramatical point of view, you should replace the second comma by a semicolon and end the question with "or does it just include subtitles?"

> If you hear Spanish voices, the movie was **dubbed in Spanish**.
>
> If you see the spanish text, you are watching the **original version
>   of the movie with Spanish subtitles**.